# Ungroup list items using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which stores the menus data in below format.

```cs
public class MenuCondiments
{
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long[] CondimentIds { get; set; }
}
```

e.g.

| GroupId | Name | CondimentIds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Veg Burger | 100032,100033,100045,100056 |
| 22 | Chiken Burger | 100067,100040,100034 |

Now, I want the output data as below in the class by using linq.

```cs
public class Condiments
{
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long CondimentIds { get; set; }
}
```

| GroupId | Name | CondimentIds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Veg Burger | 100032 |
| 21 | Veg Burger | 100033 |
| 21 | Veg Burger | 100045 |
| 21 | Veg Burger | 100056 |
| 21 | Chiken Burger | 100067 |
| 22 | Chiken Burger | 100040 |
| 22 | Chiken Burger | 100034 |

Can someone assist here?

Comment: `SelectMany` is your friend

Comment: `CondimentIds` should be named `CondimentId`, because it is singular, in the `Condiments` class, which ought to be named `Condiment` because it too is singular.

Comment: List<MenuCondiments> menus = new List<MenuCondiments>();
            List<Condiments> condiments = menus.SelectMany(x => x.CondimentIds.Select(y => new Condiments{ GroupId = x.GroupId, Name = x.Name, CondimentIds = y})).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq and  [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to flatten the inner array:

```
var menuCondiements = // get menucondiments

var result = menuCondiements
               .SelectMany(                // flatten the
                 m => m.CondimentIds       // inner array
                   .Select(
                     c => new Condiment    // project to 
                     {                     // new Condiment() 
                       GroupId = m.GroupId, 
                       Name = m.Name, 
                       CondimentId = c    // here condimentId is 'c'
                     }));
```

You should also rename your class and Id to singular rather than plural form since the class represents a single object:

```
public class Condiment
{
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long CondimentId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using classic foreach language construct. Below should give you idea.

```
var menuCondimentList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MenuCondiments>
{
    new MenuCondiments {GroupId = 21, Name = "Veg Burger", CondimentIds = new long[] { 100032, 100033, 100045, 100056 } },
    new MenuCondiments {GroupId = 22, Name = "Chicken Burger", CondimentIds = new long[] { 100067, 100040, 100034 } }
};

var condimentList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Condiments>();
// Using foreach
foreach ( var menuCondiment in menuCondimentList )
{
    foreach(var c in menuCondiment.CondimentIds )
    {
        condimentList.Add(new Condiments
        {
            GroupId = menuCondiment.GroupId,
            Name = menuCondiment.Name,
            CondimentId = c
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me.

Comment: Below also worked for me.

var condimentList = menuCondimentList.SelectMany(con=> con.CondimentIds, (condiment, condiments) => new
                                             {
                                                 GroupId = condiment.GroupId,
                                                 Name = condiment.Name,
                                                 CondimentIds = condiments
                                             }
                                             )
                                        .ToList();